# LED blinking with timer interrupt

Tags: c, arm, stm32, hal

I'm trying to make two LEDs blink with a timer interrupt, but for some reason when the last function called before the while loop returns, the code seems to enter a loop (which is not the while loop obviously) from which it never exits

I'm using a STM32 Nucleo-144 for STM32H743ZI with ARM Corte-M7 core at 400MHz;
I used CubeMX for initializing the board and the desired pin. Also from CubeMX I set the timer TIM6 with a prescaler of 399999 and a period of 499 so the blinking period would be of 0.5s; The IDE I'm using is Atollic True Studio

Here's the code I'm trying to run

```
ETH_TxPacketConfig TxConfig; 

ETH_HandleTypeDef heth;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim6;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

PCD_HandleTypeDef hpcd_USB_OTG_FS;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ETH_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void);
void TIM6_IRQHandler(void);
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
     IRQn_Type TIM6_IRQn = 0;
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ETH_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  __HAL_RCC_TIM6_CLK_ENABLE();  //Enable the TIM6 peripheral

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM6_IRQn, 0, 0);  //Enable the peripheral IRQ
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM6_IRQn);


  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim6); //Start the timer
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1) //While loop free for other simultaneous operation
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Here are some other functions used for intercepting the interrupt and managing it

```
void TIM6_IRQHandler(void) {
    // Pass the control to HAL, which processes the IRQ
    HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim6);
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    // This callback is automatically called by the HAL on the UEV event
    if(htim->Instance == TIM6) {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_14); //Function that trigger a PIN
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_7);
    }
}
```

Here is the function that initialize the timer

```
static void MX_TIM6_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 1 */
  htim6.Instance = TIM6;
  htim6.Init.Prescaler = 399999;
  htim6.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim6.Init.Period = 499;
  htim6.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim6, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM6_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM6_Init 2 */

}
```

I compile without errors or warning, but the LEDs don't blink; what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the MX_GPIO_Init()

```
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0|LD3_Pin|LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(USB_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, USB_PowerSwitchOn_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : USER_Btn_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USER_Btn_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(USER_Btn_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA5 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB0 LD3_Pin LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|LD3_Pin|LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : USB_PowerSwitchOn_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USB_PowerSwitchOn_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(USB_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : USB_OverCurrent_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USB_OverCurrent_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(USB_OverCurrent_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
```

Comment: Have you configured GPIO_PIN_7 and GPIO_PIN_16 to be normal outputs and they don't collide with any of your other hardware? Have you activated the GPIO/IO clocks?

Comment: @user6556709 yes, I think I did it; I edited the question inserting the code for the MX_GPIO_Init()